# Regex for a password (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I need help creating the regex for a password.

The password can contain letters, numbers, underscores ( _ ), dollar signs ( $ ) and hyphens ( - ), must be at least 3 characters long and at most 30 characters long.

Comment: If you find yourself asking a multiple questions about a specific topic, it might be worth investing some time to learn the basics so you can solve the trivial tasks yourself. There are many tutorials around for regexes, e.g. http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/

Comment: You may find this useful http://www.regexbuddy.com/create.html

Comment: That's quite a restrictive collection of characters. Why are you forcing people to make passwords less secure by outlawing lots of common characters (such as % and ^)?

Comment: This is actually for a username, Shouldn't have put password there... Whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letters, numbers, underscores, dollar signs and hyphens are covered by this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_$-]
```

Limiting it to 3 to 30 is covered by this:

```
{3,30}
```

In the end, we can reduce it a bit by adding the case-insensitive modifier:

```
/^[a-z0-9_$-]{3,30}$/i
```

Adding the `^` and `$` force it to match from start to finish, meaning we won't be matching a subset of the tested string. Either the entire submitted string passes, or fails.

You can try it out against a few password by visiting http://regexr.com?30ru6

Comment: @keto23 My pleasure. Remember to study the solution, ask questions, and learn from these answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
/[a-z0-9_$-]{3,30}/
```

Will match according to your requirements.